# How to use deep linking and Apple App Site Association with React.js

Tags: reactjs, deep-linking, apple-app-site-associate

I have been looking far and wide and I can't seem to find any information about how to properly use apple-app-site-association/deep linking with a react.js website. I don't even have any code because I don't know where to start.

Comment: @BennKingy I did. All I did was upload my react app to my hosting service, then put the file in the public_html folder. No extra steps. It was stupidly easy.

Comment: Nice one! I got the devops guy to host the file in cloudflare at the root, bassicaly same as you. All good!